Is there a way or solution to cancel the wait for other hpx::future get function, when using HPX?
There are many parallel tasks in my projects. I use hpx::future（usually declared in std::vectorhpx::futrue） to get task result for every one. Each task takes a different amount of time. When a task is finished, if the task result is what I need, I want to cancel the execution of other tasks or cancel other hpx::future get function.
I read the hpx document in github, but not find a way to realize what I need. can anyone help me ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In fact, I want to ask whether the hpx::future can be provided cancellation function .

You have to pass a cancellation token to the launched tasks that can be used to stop their execution. You could throw a special exception to tell the waiting code that the task was cancelled.
